# Avoid columns being displayed with their maximum width in the data output tab in pgAdmin

Tags: pgadmin-4

In [pgAdmin4](https://www.pgadmin.org/) (version 5.5), when a `SELECT * FROM tablename;` query is executed, one can see on the bottom panel, under a tab called "Data Output", the resulting records for the selected columns for the specified table.

[image: screenshot of the problem]

If this table is having columns with very long string of data, e.g when encoded as JSON objects, or any [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) complex geometries, their width can be extraordinarily large, which affects the user experience negatively. Because going to some of the columns becomes a sub-pixel game when one try to grab and move the tiny horizontal slider (e.g. moving the slider half a pixel can  move several columns by more than 2x the width of the screen...).

Did I miss something in the settings?
Is there a way to fix that, e.g. by setting a maximum width value for the columns? Because when using pgAdmin out-of-the-box, they are fully expanded...

I remember that is was not the case in earlier versions (4.x).

I'm using the latest [dockerized](https://www.docker.com/) version (5.5) as documented on the pgAdmin4 [doc](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-container/) and available here: https://hub.docker.com/r/dpage/pgadmin4/

OS: Ubuntu 18.04
Web Browser: Firefox 89.0.2 (64-bit)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can set the maximum width value for columns under File -> Preferences -> Query tool -> Results grid

Max column width setting pgAdmin 4

[image: max column width setting pgAdmin 4]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I actually never went into those menus up there! Shame on me! ;)
By default the value is `0`, which probably means "use the maximum width of the selected value" for each column. This is working on version pgAdmin4  version `5.7`.

Comment: You saved my life. I've been annoyed about this for so long.

Comment: Instead of specifying Max col width we can change Columns sized by from `Column data` to `Column Name`. This will simply take width of column name instead of data. Hence, you'll always see the column name and data can be seen by double-clicking on data.

Comment: I just had to restart pgAdmin after making this change.

Answer (score 3):

In the newest version of PG Admin v6 (6.7 as of 3/18/22) they changed this yet again. It is in the same place, but the option no longer lets you set the width. There is just a radio option to have super wide columns or base the width off of the column name

[Preferences Screen PG admin 6.7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5Qs1.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am using PostgreSQL 11.17

1. Go to File menu > click on Preferences
2. From Preferences window scroll down to Query tool
3. From the list under Query Tool > click on result grid
4. Select Column name in the Columns sized by field
5. Click save
6. Reopen the table you were having issue with due to column width